# How do I reset the last stash which was recovered, but then lost the changes it contained by mistake?

Tags: git, github, git-stash, github-desktop

I was using GitHub desktop and restored a stash I had, but then as I went on with the work and mistakenly overwrote those changes in a way that cannot be recovered using VS Code. (used crtl+z to go back in the file history, then overwrote those changes by mistake).

Is there a way I can bring back the stash even though it was not discarded ?
I am on Windows 10, tried the following command, but I think it only lists the dropped stash commits : `git fsck --no-reflogs | find  "dangling commit"`

Ideally I would need a way to list all recent stash commit regardless if they were dropped or restored. Then recovering them with `git stash apply *hash*`.

**In summary** : The restore button in the picture below is what I had clicked on to apply the stash to my local repository. However, now That I lost those restored changes. I want to get back my stash so that I recover those changes, as it seems the only way I can do so.

[image]

Comment: `git stash list` lists the non-dropped stashes.

Comment: Tried it but did not help, I already solved this, will share the solution as soon as I have the time.

Comment: You'd have to ask whoever actually downvoted. I can see the individual counts (+0, -1 => no upvotes, one downvote) but not who made them. My own guess is that someone thought there was too little information in the question itself and/or that it was redundant with existing questions (but the latter should be marked duplicate, not downvoted). Given that you're on Windows I don't think it's exactly a duplicate: as you show in your answer, you needed a few more tools.

Comment: Yes, I added a summary, just in case it was not clear enough. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to recover the stash using the following commands :

- Command to list all lost/unreachable stash like commits   `git fsck --unreachable | grep commit | cut -d ' ' -f3 | xargs git log --merges --no-walk`
- Show contents with `git show *hash*` using one of the hashes listed in previous command
- If commit is the right one, recover changes with `git stash apply *hash*`.

Note that I had already tried this before posting the question on Stack overflow, but windows had not recognized those commands because they are Linux commands.To solve this, I installed cygwin which allows you to use linux commands in windows :

- Install https://www.cygwin.com/ (Follow vid for installation and setup : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zp7m7nkt-A)
- Can now use Linux commands in Cygwin Terminal
- To be able to use linux commands in windows cmd. Make sure bin folder path is available in the env path variables.
- Close all terminals, as well as GitHub desktop, then open the windows command line again at the project root folder then execute `ls` command. If it lists your directories folders and files, it means that your configuration was successful.

Comment: You are a lifesaver, the first command worked great.